# azkaban build failed: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':azkaban-common:compileClasspath'

Tags: azkaban

Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
when run ./gradlew clean build ,it returns :

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   * What went wrong:
>   Could not resolve all files for configuration ':azkaban-common:compileClasspath'                                                                                        .
>   Could not download hadoop-hdfs.jar (org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-hdfs:2.6.1)
>   Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs/2.6.1/hadoop-hdfs-2.6.1.jar'.
>   Connection reset
>   I try to open https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs/2.6.1/hadoop-hdfs-2.6.1.jar this link in navigator,it returns "404 Not Found".
>   how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can add required Hadoop jar files in classpath before running Azkaban build, this will solve the issue.

Run below command for same. 
export CLASSPATH = (Hadoop jar path)